After upgrade, php error file_get_contents
After upgrading from Civi 5.64 to Civi 5.75, CiviCRM throws a fatal error:
ValueError: Path cannot be empty in file_get_contents() (line 540 of xxxx/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/CRM/Core/Resources.php)

It seems to have to do with the file bower_components/smartmenus/dist/css/sm-core-css.css file which is referenced in an array on line 535 of Resources.php  If I comment that file out, CiviCRM returns but without proper css styling, menu gone etc.
I have checked that this file exists and is not empty in /libraries/civicrm/civicrm-core (Drupal site)
Here is the code from Resources.php with line commented out:
$items = [
      ///'bower_components/smartmenus/dist/css/sm-core-css.css',
      'css/crm-menubar.css',
      "css/menubar-$cms.css",
    ];
    foreach ($items as $item) {
      $content .= file_get_contents(self::singleton()->getPath('civicrm', $item));
    }

Grateful for any advice on how to debug this.

I tried cloning the repo from GitHub to a fresh install on local, but the error persists. Help!
